# f1_score() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 positional arguments (and 1 keyword-only argument) were given

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, metrics, medical, medical-imaging

````
 from sklearn.metrics import f1_score


 F1_score = f1_score(lab2d, pred2d, [0, 1, 2, 3], average=None)
print("Validation Dice Coefficient.... ")
print("Background:", F1_score[0])
print("CSF:", F1_score[1])
print("GM:", F1_score[2])
print("WM:", F1_score[3])
 ```
````

This is the error

```
f1_score() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 positional arguments (and 1  keyword-only argument) were given
```

I tried to pass the arguments in diffrerent ways but still got the same error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.f1_score.html) for version 1.2.0 states, you need to call the function like

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
y_pred = [0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1]
f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average='macro')
```

Please note that it accepts 3 arguments: `y_true`, `y_pred` and keyword argument `average`. You are trying to put one extra argument in: `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. Either it or one of the previous two arguments (`lab2d` or `pred2d`) should be removed.

In [older versions](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.20.X/sklearn/metrics/classification.py), however, it was possible to use `labels` argument on this position without naming it explicitly. If that's the case, you might try to write this line like

```
f1_score(lab2d, pred2d, labels=[0, 1, 2, 3], average=None)
```

Comment: I know this. Is there any way to pass three ararguments ?

Comment: No. Programming does not work like this. The function accepts only that number of arguments because it can only process that number of arguments. It has no idea what to do with the extra one you provided. What are you trying to achieve, and why do you want so badly to feed the extra one to the poor function?

Comment: I know. But I want to add this [0, 1, 2, 3] for this print("Background:", F1_score[0])
print("CSF:", F1_score[1])
print("GM:", F1_score[2])
print("WM:", F1_score[3])
 ```

Comment: Thank you for clarification, but I still cannot understand unfortunately. You use a function - it only knows what to do with two arguments. Imagine you go to ATM, insert card, input your PIN - and then you type a long text on the screen keyboard because you want ATM to print it on your receipt. Despite your wish, ATM will not understand what to do and will give you an error. Why do you want to print this arrray? What do the variables you are using (`lab2d`, `pred2d`, `[0, 1, 2, 3]`) actually mean?

Comment: I'm puzzled at the moment. That function has been always accepting two arguments only, even in earlier versions which existed back then in 2020. Can you just remove this extra array and share the outcome? If you get any new error or discrepancy which is too big to write in the comment, please update the original question to reflect it.

Comment: So, try to run it just like this: `f1_score(lab2d, pred2d, average=None)`

Comment: I did it but I want with [0, 1, 2, 3]

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to. It could be a typo in the initial project code, or the author was using some other library (which is unlikely), or he has modified library code in some way. Current library version will not allow you to put 3 unnamed arguments there, you can check the line #1032 in the definition: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py. Could you please share what happens if you run it without this argument? Do you receive any error, or the output is not the one you expect it to be?

Comment: Ah! I think I found it ^___^

Comment: See, in one of the previous versions there was an argument "labels" there: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.20.X/sklearn/metrics/classification.py (line 620). Previously, you could use it unnamed; now in the latest version, you have to mention the argument name (`labels`) explicitly.

Comment: So, try to run your code like this: `f1_score(lab2d, pred2d, labels=[0, 1, 2, 3], average=None)`. That should bring you the desired result, insha'Allah :)

Comment: I got the desired result.Thank you !

Comment: I already marked your answer

Comment: Thank you for checking and confirming. Good luck in your studies!